# Recursivley adding nodes to a tree

Tags: python, oop, recursion, tree

I have a problem in which I am trying to construct a tree (not always binary). Given a node at any depth of the tree, I wish to be able to add N new nodes to a `children` list attribute. The following example code results in child nodes being recursivley generated and each new child node in `self.children` contains a copy of itself.

```
class Node:

    # Constructor to create a Node
    def __init__(self, data, children=[]):
        self.value = data
        self.children = children

    @classmethod
    def spawn(cls, data):
        return cls(data)

    def spawn_child(self, data):
        child = self.spawn(data)
        self.children.append(child)


def max_depth(node):
    if len(node.children) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        depths = []
        for child in node.children:
            depths.append(max_depth(child))
        return np.max(depths)+1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Let us create following example tree
         50
        / \
        30   70
     """

    root = Node(50)
    root.spawn_child(30)
    root.spawn_child(70)
    print(max_depth(root))  # results in RecursionError
```

Upon checking the `max_depth` of the tree here we get an error. We have infact created the tree,

```
         50
        / \
        30    70
       / \   / \
      30 70  30  70
      /   \  /   \
      30  70 30  70
     /     \ /    \
     .     . .     .
     .     . .     .
     .     . .     .
```

Upon removing the keyword argument `children=[]` and rewritting the constructor as,

```
class Node:

    # Constructor to create a Node
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.value = data
        self.children = []
```

we stop the recursive generation of child nodes and generate the correct tree i.e. one root node with a value of 50 which has two children (30 and 70). Now the correct value of `max_depth()` is printed as `1`.

How does including the `children` attribute as a default keyword with a value corrosponding to an empty list cause this behaviour?

Comment: It probably is me, but I don't understand anything of this code. Sometimes `point` or `points` is a value, sometimes it is an index, ... very confusing. I gave up.

Comment: @trincot `point` is the value which corrosponds to each of the unique elements in each sublist (`members_snapshot`) in the `members_list`. `points` corrosponds to the indexes in `members_snapshot` which are equal to that unique value. So `unique_points = [1, 0]`, which is then iterated over and the indexes where `members_snapshot` equal that unique index is stored in `points`. So `points = [0, 1]` and `[2, 3]` i.e. the elements where `members_snapshot` equal 0 and 1 respectivley

Comment: Well, I just don't understand the code. Can you edit your question and give a few non-trivial examples of input and the graph you want to get from it (as a drawing or as a JSON structure)? Maybe that will clarify the logic you have  in mind.

Comment: @trincot I have simplified the example a bit. I have found the cause of the issue but do not understand why it exists.

Comment: Thanks. You fell for a trap that is specific for Python: your code uses a default value for a parameter that is mutated (`children`). See duplicate reference.